# Is there a way to get someone's IP address while he is connected to a server?

Tags: networking, social-networking

I'm new here and to all of this stuff but there is a question on my mind for a long time that I didn't find an answer to it. My question is, is there any possible way for someone to get my or someone's else IP address if they are both connected to the same server? For example, let's say that person A and person B are playing a video game that uses dedicated servers, is there any possible way of person A to get the IP address of person B? I know that they can get the IP address of the server that they are connected to it but is there a way for some of them to get even more information and get the IP address of the other client that is connected to the same server?

As I said I'm still a newbie to all this networking stuff so any info would be appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: Before asking next question please read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic and https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

It all depends on how the application is built, if its only communicating to the server and its not passing the IP to the other clients then its not possible. If the Application have a peer-2-peer functionality you should be able to do "netstat -a" in CMD and see the IP of the other client. Alternative you need to access the server itself.

Answer (score 0):

Not without having the administrative access to the server itself (or if application that they both use, offers this information - but this is rare currently).